# SAP - See all table entries in SE16 for table with numeric key

Tags: hana, sap-basis, sap-data-dictionary, sap-r3

I'm trying to inspect the data of a table via transaction code `SE16`(n) on a development system. I'd like to see all of the table's records. In other words, I don't want there to be any selection criteria. But the table has a numeric key that I have to specify. Is there a wildcard-like value that I can enter so any record matches the key?

Thanks in advance,
Joshua

EDIT (taken from OP comments):

> *"It's an old custom table/Z-table. When I just press F8 without putting in anything for the key field I get the message: "No table entries found for specified key" The key's data type is NUMERIC (length 8) (it's an HROBJID actually). Putting in from 00000000 to 99999999 doesn't work."*
>
> **Solution**: *"The problem was indeed that there was no data in the table on this system. It was not obvious to me that I could leave a key field blank. Thank you all for your help."*

Comment: Which table is that? Which field of that table? What happens if you leave the field empty?

Comment: It's an old custom table/Z-table. When I just press F8 without putting in anything for the key field I get the message: "No table entries found for specified key"

The key's data type is NUMERIC (length 8) (it's an HROBJID actually). Putting in from 00000000 to 99999999 doesn't work.

Comment: Does the table have any entry at all?

Comment: Are you sure there's any data in it? Also check su53 or try to debug, maybe theres's some custom code (enchancement, badi, whatever) which prevents you from getting the data.

Comment: By default all lines should be displayed up to the maximum defined in the selection screen. If you click the button "Number of entries", you can see how many lines there are in the table (NB: it counts only the lines in the current client if the table is client-dependent). Sometimes the selection may not work well if the selected field has a "kind of defective" Conversion Exit.

Comment: The problem was indeed that there was no data in the table on this system. It was not obvious to me that I could leave a key field blank. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In transaction codes `SE16` and `SE16N`, by default all the lines of the selected table should be displayed up to the maximum defined in the selection screen (leave the field blank to display all).

If you click the button "Number of entries", you can see how many lines there are in the table (NB: it counts only the lines in the current client if the table is client-dependent).

Sometimes the selection may not work well if the selected table field has a "kind of defective" Conversion Exit (at Domain level in the ABAP Dictionary), but that happens rarely.